# Starting a task when an Observable ticks and merge results (using Rx.NET)

Tags: task, observable, system.reactive

I am wondering if it is possible to start a task every time an Observable ticks and continue the pipeline with the results from these tasks. The order of the result does not matter. I am using C#.

```
linksObservable
    .Select(url=> downloadTask(url))
    ...
```

The above code would start the tasks to download the urls but how do I get the results as they are available (i.e downloadTask is finished). Another consideration is `Exceptions` from a task. Any exception should not impact the rest of the tasks.

Comment: Just wondering if `linksObservable.Select(url=> Observable.Return(await downloadTask(url))).Switch()` could be the answer.

Comment: No. In the event of concurrent tasks, `Switch` would cancel the earlier one. If you replaced `Switch`with `Merge` that would work, and be equivalent to Peter's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if  `downloadTask` returns something you can do

```
observable
    .SelectMany(url => downloadTask(url))
    .Subscribe(result => Console.WriteLine(result));
```

Complete example:

```
void Main()
{
    var observable = new Subject<string>();

    observable
        .SelectMany(url => downloadTask(url))
        .Subscribe(result => Console.WriteLine(result));

    observable.OnNext("a");
    observable.OnNext("b");
    observable.OnNext("c");
    observable.OnNext("d");
}

public async Task<string> downloadTask(string s)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return s;
}
```